# Nest JS middleware .exclude option is not blocking the middleware for excluded routes

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

I am trying to exclude some routes for the middleware. The **.exclude** option is not working. Instead the middleware is applied for the excluded routes too

This is the code for **Middleware**
[image]

This is the code for **User Module**
[image]

This is the code for **User controller**
[image]

I guess my code should block the middleware for the 'users' GET route... but it is allowing middleware for the blocked route.

Comment: this code looks fine. I didn't manage to reproduce this. Which version of Nestjs are you using exactly? I tested with `8.2.0`

Comment: @MicaelLevic   8.1.4

Answer (score 6):

this works:

```
consumer
    .apply(CheckRoleMiddleware)
    .exclude(
    { path: '/page', method: RequestMethod.GET }
).forRoutes({path: '*', method: RequestMethod.ALL})
```

full path was /api/page, but if use it at exclude, it not works.
So I used relative path '/page' instead absolute '/api/page', absolute was not working.

at main.ts was defined

```
app.setGlobalPrefix('api');
```

Comment: I switched from version 8 to version 10, and yeah, this is solution now. In v8, you had to include all prefixes

Answer (score -1):

Adding a prefix to exclude the route path should resolve your issue.

In the below example I define a global prefix ('/api/v1'), so now when you want to exclude a route the application writes the complete path (including all prefixes) to that route:

```
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer);

  {consumer
    .apply(LoggerMiddleware)
    .exclude(
      // 'api/v1' prefix to that route
      { path: 'api/v1/user', method: RequestMethod.POST },
    )
    .forRoutes(UserController);
  }
};
```